# Execute stored procedure named as a string

Tags: sql, stored-procedures

How can I execute a stored procedure named as a string

I tried this:

```
EXEC CAST(@GetDD AS StoredProcedure);
```

Comment: It's not very clear what you're asking. Are you trying to create a stored procedure in the database from a string, or are you trying to execute SQL statements that are stored in a string? Or something else entirely...?

Comment: execute stored procedure named as a string ... what's wrong in a question ... ?

Comment: Since you asked what's wrong with the question: (1) You don't state what you're trying to achieve, but somehow expect us to infer from an incorrect code sample. (2) You don't bother with correct grammar, spelling or punctuation, which is generally considered good form in the professional world. (3) You clarify your question in a comment rather than editing the question to make it more clear.

Comment: You got a point, but I though the question was understandable from a header and code sample, failed with that, thank you for advice, don't be aggressive :3 sometimes that's hard to ask question very correct, also with my English, but I will try do it better _^ also I will rewrite topic to description _^ thank you Andomar.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a dynamic SQL string, and execute that:

```
declare @sql varchar(512);
set @sql = 'exec ' + @GetDD;
EXEC (@sql);
```